# Have multiple dataframes stored in a dict. Essentially performing a vlookup with the 1st DF vs the others. Want to make it more Pythonic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am seeing if the common value "CUSIP" is in the dataframe broker1, broker2 and broker 3.  If it is, it will insert a new column into the first dataframe, "Summary" along with the value found in the "price" column of the respective dataframes.

The code below works however how do I make it better? I am not sure how to look a dictionary.

`x1` is a dictionary containing "worksheet: the dataframne".
`x1` has keys Summary, Broker1, Broker2, Broker3 which are dataframes. Each dataframe contains CUSIP and PRICE as a column.

```
x1['Summary']['Broker1'] = x1['Summary']['CUSIP'].map(x1['Broker1'].set_index('CUSIP')['Price'])
x1['Summary']['Broker2'] = x1['Summary']['CUSIP'].map(x1['Broker2'].set_index('CUSIP')['Price'])
x1['Summary']['Broker3'] = x1['Summary']['CUSIP'].map(x1['Broker3'].set_index('CUSIP')['Price'])
```

The code works but I want to condense it or make it more pythonic. As you could imagine, if i had 40 worksheets, this would mean cutting and pasting 40 lines.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of each DataFrame along with the matching expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a minimal reproducible example for clarity, but it looks like a simple `for` loop should be enough:

```
for broker in ['Broker1', 'Broker2', 'Broker3']:
    x1['Summary'][broker] = (x1['Summary']['CUSIP']
                             .map(x1[broker].set_index('CUSIP')['Price'])
                            )
```

I think you might even be able to do it in one shot with [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
brokers = ['Broker1', 'Broker2', 'Broker3']
x1['Summary'][brokers] = (pd.concat([x1[broker].set_index('CUSIP')['Price']
                                     for broker in brokers], axis=1)
                            .reindex(x1['Summary']['CUSIP'])
                          )
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am relatively new to Stack, I'll definitely keep the pointer in mind next time.

Comment: @PyNub did the above solution work for you?

Comment: Yes. the 1st solution worked. Trying the second solution though as my actual code is a little bit more involved.